# Does MySQL support 'Create Assertion' statement like below?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, assertion

Below code is a create assertion example I tried to implement in mysql but it seems the mysql does not like it. So the question is that did I do something wrong in the code below?

```
CREATE ASSERTION dept_manager_constraint
CHECK ((SELECT salary FROM dept_manager >=50000)) NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

I also tried to Alter the table and add the check assertion. Does below code same as the code above?

```
ALTER TABLE dept_manager
ADD CHECK (salary>=50000);
```

If they are different, what are the difference between creating assertion and alter the table with adding a check statement.

Comment: No current DBMS supports assertions (as defined in the SQL standard) to my knowledge

Comment: Where did you get the syntax for the check assertion code?

Comment: I found it on internet @P.Salmon but do not remember where. It seems there is no assertion in mysql

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't support ASSERTION but introduced CHECK at the version 8.0.16. Prior to that it just ignores the clause.

There is two differences between CHECK and ASSERTION:

The first is that CHECK is always true when the table is empty. So, some constraint checking for content in a table will be useless with the CHECK clause.

The second difference is that the ASSERTION is checked at the schema level.

Would be nice to have support for ASSERTION in MySQL.